# AvalonDock, check docking content

Tags: wpf, docking, avalondock

I need allow or no docking according the content.

For more detail,  I use some DocmentPane with some DocumentContent. I want allow the behaviour floatting for the DocumentContent, but i dont want allow DocumentContent change DocumentPane. DocumentPane can only redock on original DocumentPane.

I dont know how process. I dont find drog event to check and accept the content. My DocumentPane is herited class, else i can overwrite some methodes. But DocumentPane dont have virtual Drog method.

Thank for your helps.

Comment: I searched for the AvalonDock documentation and all that's there is a tutorial that doesn't talk about events, so I can't get into specific code.  Is there a `Docking` event or an `OnDocking` method that you can override?  Here's a link to an article I found about using AvalonDock with MVVM: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/239342/AvalonDock-and-MVVM

Comment: Nothing can be overwriting (or I don t find). I can only check item list who is readOnlyObservable. I will try delve in this direction.